# clsql connect oracle database

Tags: oracle, lisp, clsql

I am doing some practice with `clsql`. I want to connect my oracle server hence my connection function is;

`(connect '("192.168.2.3" "xe" "username" "password") :database-type :oracle)`

when i hit the return, the following error message shows up.

`Couldn't load foreign libraries "libclntsh", "oci". (searched *FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*)
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]`

I have already installed `oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.1.0-1.i386.rpm`

and define `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib`

So, what else should I do to connect the server?

Comment: What operating system?  What Lisp compiler?  How is CLSQL installed (asdf-install, clbuild, etc)?

Comment: When I had trouble connecting to MySQL, part of the trouble was word length: the OS, Lisp, and MySQL libraries were a mix of 32- and 64-bit.  (I never got it to work completely, but fixing this at least caused it to fail later in the process!)

Comment: I am using linux (fedora 13), my lisp interpreter is sbcl and i installed clsql by clbuild. I also got similar error with mysql as well.

Comment: Do the files mentioned in the error message exist somewhere on your system?  If so, where?  And are the directories where these files exist (if they do) in FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS, which I suspect is a collection of some sort in your LISP environment?

Answer (score 2):

I was playing with oracle lately and found out that all you need is to put path to `libclntsh` into `/etc/ld.conf.d/oracle.conf`

My setup was following( redhat,centos - as root): downloaded from oracle

```
oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
install via rpm -ivh oracle*.rpm
```

Create file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`:

`/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib`

then execute `ldconfig`

Now as `clsql-oracle` is not in `quicklisp`, I downloaded and extracted `clsql-6.6.2`, then

```
(require "asdf")
(push #P"/opt/jeff/clsql-6.6.2/" asdf:*central-registry*)
(asdf:load-system :clsql-oracle)
(defparameter *some-db* (connect '("127.0.0.1:1521/db1" "SOME_USER_RO" "*******") :database-type :oracle))
```

and voila, it works

Comment: following your suggestions on ld.so.conf and running ldconfig has helped me to go past the error

Answer (score 1):

One thing that trips me up with dynamic linking to the Oracle libs (in C/C++ that is), is the fact that the libclntsh.so shared object comes with the version **after** the so name. So you may need to create a soft link in the same directory, ensuring that the soft link name is just libclntsh.so

Comment: I think this should be part of my answer, thanks for pointing out - sometimes you simply have everything but the name of the '.so'' file correct, because it has specific oracle version included. Some packages have that thing ready for you, some do not - like on debian, and early oracle's *.rpm. So definitely, if you created ldconfig entry, and it is still not working, check name of libclnt.so file or link presence